# Get custom NavigationController class from custom UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I am trying to implement the side navigation menu (one that we have in Android) in iOS App.So far i tried the following:-

[image: mystoryboard]

AppDelegate.swift :-

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
 var window: UIWindow?
 var bridge: RCTBridge!

 func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
   didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: 
 [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

 let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "mystoryboard", bundle: Bundle.main)
 let rootViewController: UIViewController = 
 sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: 
 "NativeLabelSwiftViewController") as UIViewController

 let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: 
 rootViewController)

 window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
 window!.rootViewController = navigationController
 window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

 return true
}
```

The above is my AppDelegate class since it is a React Native project we have the generated code as well.Here added the following code to instantiate my rootViewClass(NativeLabelSwift) by following code :-

```
  let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "mystoryboard", bundle: Bundle.main)
  let rootViewController: UIViewController = 
   sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: 
  "NativeLabelSwiftViewController") as UIViewController
```

NavigationLabelSwiftViewController.swift(Custom View Class) :-

```
 class NativeLabelSwiftViewController: UIViewController{

   var bridge: RCTBridge!
   override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

     title = "Production Tracking"
     let btn2 = UIButton(type: .custom)
     btn2.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
     btn2.addTarget(self,
     action:#selector(NativeLabelSwiftViewController.
     onBtn2Clicked.(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    let item2 = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btn2)

    self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(item2, animated: true)
  }

  @IBAction func onBtn2Clicked(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    if let navViewController = self.navigationController as? 
     NavigationController {
       // navigation view controller is available
   }
  else{
    // navigation view controller not available
  } 
}

}
```

The Navigation Controller has a UIViewController class (NativeLabelSwiftViewController) that has a button in Tab Bar.On Press of the Button i need to access the Navigation Controller method.But i am not able to get the navigation controller using the below code :-

```
     let navViewController = self.navigationController as? 
     NavigationController;   //this is NIL
```

But

```
      let uiViewController = self.navigationController as? 
      UINavigationController;   //this is not NIL
```

Comment: WHAT IS THE ISSUE ??

Comment: Anbu, have you tried implementing the side menu using libraries via Cocoapods / Carthage? It does not answer your question directly, but it might solve your problem.

Comment: @dahiya_boy please read the code before commenting.In onBtn2Clicked function i am getting the reference of navigationcontroller as NIL.

Comment: @edopelawi thanks for the suggestion but since i want to implement myself without any library.

Comment: @anbuselvan can you accept my answer if it solved your problem?

Answer (score 2):

You are not referring your custom navigation controller in the AppDelegate. You used `UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootViewController)`.

You if you want to use the storyBoard NavigationController, In AppDelegate use -

```
let nav = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NavigationController") as! NavigationController

window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
window!.rootViewController = nav
window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
return true
```

Note: Don't forget to put an Identifier for the StoryBoard NavigationController.

Comment: No need of `if-else` here.